# How to load scripts in website front-end but not Elementor editor through functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor, wp-enqueue-scripts

I am trying to enqueue a couple scripts and stylesheet on the home page of my website, but not have them load in the Elementor editor. [As per this thread](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/5509), I have used `\Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode()` to determine if the site is in Elementor edit mode:

```
function mysite_child_enqueue_scripts_styles() {
    if ( is_front_page() && ! \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->editor->is_edit_mode() ) {
        // Enqueue stylesheet
        wp_enqueue_style( 'mysite-child-preloader', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/preloader.css', array() );

        // Enqueue scripts
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mysite-child-modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/modernizr.custom.js', array(), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mysite-child-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mysite-child-preloader', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/preloader.js', array(), null, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mysite_child_enqueue_scripts_styles' );
```

This did not work however and i'm not sure why. The scripts still load in the Elementor editor when I inspect element and search for them. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about checking the url string for elementor?

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'elementor') === false ) {
    // load scripts
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this seemed to work fine, though probably not the cleanest method. Any ideas why the code I provided above wouldn't work?

Comment: Ok, yes this is not the best solution but a a solution that works for the first time. Do you get some errors in your log files?

Comment: Nope, no errors.